# Screen Painting question

Tags: translation

We've had this Japanese screen painting for about 20 years; however, we were told a long time ago that the artist is actually Chinese. Does anyone know who this artist might be?

[image]

Comment: The signature is "廣狄". No idea who he is/was though.